# dbx : display very large string

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, solaris, dbx

I wish to know how can I display a very large string (>4K) in "dbx" ?
my string is more than 2MB ?
Is there any limit on the size of arguments that can be passed in solaris ?

Thanks
Arpit

Comment: Do you have a program with a large string and a running dbx?  Perhaps you could expand your question by showing what happens when you try to print such a string in dbx.  Also:  Why do you care about passing arguments?  Is that related to the dbx question?

Comment: I would suggest installing (perhaps after compiling it) a `gdb` for Solaris. AFAIK `gdb` can be told to display large strings.